# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" crossfilter

Tags: csv, d3.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to visualize a relatively small `.csv` file on a map using crossfilter.

This is a [live version](http://edsa-project.eu/resources/dashboard/) of the site, for development purposes I'm running the same code on my `localhost`.

When I use [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-matthew-english/data_demo/master/adzuna_X.csv), (*3037* lines) everything works tolerably well, however when I switch to [a file just flightly larger](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-matthew-english/data_demo/master/adzuna_Y.csv) (*3,871* lines) it crashes.

I thought maybe it had something to do with rouge `&` characters in my data, but that isn't it!

Can anyone figure out what is the issue here?

Does it have something to do with size?

It don't think that could be- because I have a larger file and crossfilter works fine on that.

I really can't see what are the substantive differences between the two files!

Comment: Probably a formatting issue with one of the rows. I'd suggest a "binary search" to find the problem. (Split the file in two; try each part to identify the failing half; repeat as necessary)

Comment: wow- you're a genius! I was just going row by row like a monkey idiot. do you know how I could split it in two, maybe using python or perl or something?

Answer (score 4):

You are defining your dimensions like this:

```
var countries = data.dimension(function (d) {
    return d["Country"];
});
```

The problem is almost certainly that somewhere in your dataset, one of these dimension accessors returns an `undefined` value. This breaks the rule that a dimension accessor [must always return naturally ordered values](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension). You should make a small change to your dimension accessors and always return a value of the same type. For strings:

```
var countries = data.dimension(function (d) {
    return d["Country"] ? d["Country"] : "";
});
```

For numbers:

```
var countries = data.dimension(function (d) {
    return d["Country"] ? d["Country"] : 0;
});
```

The exact accessor you use depends on the structure of your data, but hopefully this will help. I'm sure in the additional records you add, you have some empty field somewhere.